# Characteristic function differentiable at 0

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable on a probability space and $\phi$ be its characteristic function defined as $\phi(\theta)=\mathbb{E}(e^{i\theta X})$. Assume that $\phi^{'}(0)=z\in\mathbb{C}$. Then necessarily $z=ia$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$.
I just managed to prove this when $\mathbb{E}|X|<\infty$. Apply dominate convergence theorem I can prove that $\phi^{'}(0)=i\mathbb{E}(X)$. But for the general case I have few idea.
Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\phi$ is differentiable at $0$ so is its real part. Hence $\lim_{\theta \to 0}E \frac {1-\cos (\theta X)} {\theta}$ exists. The right hand limit here is $\geq0$ and the left hand limit is $\leq 0$. Hence the limit can only be $0$. It follows that the real part of $\phi'(0)$ is $0$.

Comment: It's interesting! Thank you so much for your help!